# Fonts not building in Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have fonts in my assets/fonts folder. In the assets/common folder there is a _fonts.scss file where I include fonts using @font-face and then import them into the main main.scss file.

When I build the build, the fonts don't appear in the dist folder, that is, they don't build. How can this problem be solved?

```js
// webpack config
const path = require("path");
const outputPath = "dist";
const entryPoint = "assets/js";

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, entryPoint, "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, outputPath),
    clean: true,
    filename: "scripts.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          miniCss.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              url: false
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [require("postcss-preset-env")],
              },
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        generator: {
          filename: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new miniCss({
      filename: "style.css",
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your logs? Also, should this `filename: "fonts/[name].[ext]"` be `filename: "assets/fonts/[name].[ext]"` ?

Comment: No, there are no errors. It's just that the fonts don't appear in the dist folder. I tried different options and your suggested one, but still the fonts do not build

Comment: What about [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/huantaoliu/8ea366c15ea18e02cc53839fff1ed04d/raw/52552088c032825e0a8d9d535ce3f357ce9aacce/webpack.config.js) (check the bottom of the code)?

Answer (score 0):

Try changenging the filename from: `fonts/[name].[ext]` to `fonts/[name][ext]`

Basically without the dot, webpack automatically appends a dot in the file extension name. With your changes the file generated would be: fonts/fontname..tff. It could explain why it couldn't find it in the dist folder.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
{
  loader: "css-loader",
  options: {
   url: true
  },
},
```